# How to get (sub)directories in an Android FireMonkey application?

Tags: android, delphi, debugging

We have an Android app and in the DocumentsPath we have a subfolder called *'default'*

However when we retrieve the directories from the DocumentsPath, the folder doesn't show up.

**Does have someone any idea how to do it?**

The code is as follows:

```
procedure TdmoMain.SetupDirArray;
var
  mDirs: TStringDynArray;
begin
  RootDir := TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
  {$if defined(MSWINDOWS)}
    mDirs:=TDirectory.GetDirectories(RootDir, '[!_]*'); //on Windows no directories which start with '_'
  {$ELSE}
    mDirs:=TDirectory.GetDirectories(RootDir); 
  {$ENDIF}

  if High(mDirs)>0 then //this should be always true BUT IT IS NOT (IOW at least one subdir - album installed)
  begin
    SetHomeDir; //do some processing here
  end
  else //unfortunately it goes here
  begin
    { DEBUG CODE BEGIN }
    SetLength(mDirs, 1);
    mDirs[0]:=TPath.Combine(RootDir, 'default');
    if TDirectory.Exists(mDirs[0]) then
      ShowMessage('Puzzled!'); //this shows up!!!
    { DEBUG CODE END }

//    ShowMessage('You do not have any subdirectories!');
  end;
end;
```

We're using Delphi XE6.

Comment: are you sure that `default` is a directory, and not some virtual location or symlink or etc.?
I'm not android power user or developer, just guessing. if `TDirectory` says it doesn't exist, then may be it really doesn't and it is not directory?

Comment: @teran: I'm sure. It is created by Delphi's deployment engine and we have files inside. If I do a TDirectory.GetFiles(RootDir+'default') I can even retrieve the files which I put inside via installation (some jpeg, an ini, a SQLite db etc.)

Comment: Do some debugging. Why does the function return false. Trace through it.

Comment: What is de documents path on android? Or in the apk as you say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

The problem was in `if High(mDirs)>0` which for one directory returns **False**.

High(mDirs) is the index of the highest element in the array which for a dynamic array with one element is 0. It should be `Length(mDirs)>0`

Thanks everyone.